# iCalendar repeat rule for x days before the 2nd Tuesday in the month

Tags: icalendar

I have a meeting on every 2nd Tuesday of the month.
I need 10 days to prepare that meeting - this means I would need a recurring event "10 days before the 2nd Tuesday of the month"
(added via ical file)

I found [iCalendar repeat rule for "the day after the second monday of the month"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61663797/icalendar-repeat-rule-for-the-day-after-the-second-monday-of-the-month) but I'm not sure how/if this applies to my situation/how to remodel it to fit my needs.
The issue is that since it's 10 days prior it may even be in the previous month in some cases (e.g. if the first day of the month is a Tuesday)

What is the correct command for this?

EDIT: the time is always from 8-10am just so it can be included.

Comment: Your question is about using specific MacOS software (as opposed to programming), please post it here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Actually @sesm, the OP doesn't mention how he is creating the ical file.  Icalendar is not operating system specific.  It may not strictly be programming, more how to code an event using the RFC 5545 specification. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545

Comment: HI, not sure it's possible.  I thought maybe you'd have to have two RRULES, one for  & first Saturday BYDAY=+SA and BYMONTHDAY=1,2,3,4,5,6   and the other where BYDAY=-SA and BYSETPOS=5 (? the fifth saturday)    I haven't run the variations, you'd have to do that to check you don't get too many sundays, and what happens with February.   Note also that not all calendar applications cope with all the 'BY' options.  So best to check that before investing too much time.  There was this, but it is old 2009 https://www.calconnect.org/tests/iCalendar-RRULE-Interop/iCalendar-RRULE-Interop-Matrix.html